# how to fetch the input value entered using sweetalert?

Tags: sweetalert, sweetalert2

using attribute ' type: "input" ', i am able enter value in textbox. I need to know how to fetch the input value .
Below is my code :

input:"text" is not working ...I tried fetching value using json.parse ...nothing is working. Please help me to fetch and store the value

swal({
                    title: "Your order summary is ***",
                    text: "Proceed to checkout",
                    //type: "success",
                    type: "input",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#EF5350",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                    cancelButtonText: "No",
                    closeOnConfirm: false,
                    showLoaderOnConfirm: false
                },
                function(isConfirm){
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        var gstva = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                        var dataString = {"pushCount":/*pushCount*/0, "LECount":LECount,"gst": gstva};
                        $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url: "store/requestPurchase",
                            data: dataString,
                            async: false,
                            success: function(response){
                                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                                var response = obj.result;

Answer (score 0):

```
swal({
                        title: "Your order summary is - <?php echo $price->country_detail; ?> - "+totalCost+"/- + Taxes",
                        text: "Proceed to checkout",
                        type : "input",
                        inputPlaceholder: "Enter your GST number(optional)",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                        closeOnConfirm: false,
                },
                function(inputValue,isConfirm){
                    if (((inputValue === "") || (inputValue !== "")) && (inputValue !== false)){
                        var dataString = {"pushCount":0, "LECount":LECount, "gstValue":inputValue};
```

Comment: Using "inputValue" , one can retrieve the contents from the sweetalert textbox input